# How to customize list environment exclusively for tabulars?

Tags: tables, enumitem

I would like to implement a list within a tabular environment. Without adjustments the output looks pretty akward due to horizontal spacing. However, I used the following code to align the list directly to the left hand side of the tabular environment:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\minipagetrue}{\@minipagetrue}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,after=\vskip-\baselineskip,label=     {\textbullet},leftmargin=*,before=\minipagetrue,}
```

Plugging this code into a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,hideothersubsections]{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e,array,longtable}

%------LAYOUT--------
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

%defining color of itemize.
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{yellow}$\blacksquare$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\color{orange}$\blacktriangleright$}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\minipagetrue}{\@minipagetrue}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,after=\vskip-\baselineskip,label=    {\textbullet},leftmargin=*,before=\minipagetrue,}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight}p{30mm}>{\RaggedRight}p{30mm}>{\RaggedRight}p{30mm}}

\onslide<2->{text 1} & \onslide<2->{text 2} & \onslide<2->{text 3}\\

\begin{itemize}%[leftmargin=0mm]
  \item<3-> subitem
\end{itemize}

\end{tabular}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

However, I observe two problems with my output. Firstly, the code presented first is a global code and hence refers to all list environments; I would like it to refer exclusively to list environments within a tabular.
Secondly, the definition of colors of the bulletpoints disappears using the package > enumitem.

Is it possible to address both issues? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `\setbeamercolor` to change the color of beamer elements:

```
% defining color of itemize.
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=yellow}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=orange}
% defining shape of items
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}$\blacksquare$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize subitem}$\blacktriangleright$}
```

Then you can define the item and the subitem label for `itemize` using `enumitem`

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\usebeamertemplate{itemize subitem}}
```

If you want a special list for tables you can define a new one:

```
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[tabitemize]{nosep,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[tabitemize,1]{label=\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}\textbullet}
\setlist[tabitemize,2]{label=\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize subitem}\textbullet}
```

Now you can use `tabitemize` inside tables and `itemize` outside tables.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,hideothersubsections]{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e,array,longtable}

%------LAYOUT--------
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

% defining color of itemize.
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=yellow}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=orange}
% defining shape of items
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}$\blacksquare$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize subitem}$\blacktriangleright$}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\usebeamertemplate{itemize subitem}}
% define tabitmize for tables
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[tabitemize]{nosep,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[tabitemize,1]{label=\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}\textbullet}
\setlist[tabitemize,2]{label=\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize subitem}\textbullet}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight}p{30mm}>{\RaggedRight}p{30mm}>{\RaggedRight}p{30mm}}
  \onslide<2->{text 1} & \onslide<2->{text 2} & \onslide<2->{text 3}\\
  \begin{tabitemize}
    \item<3-> item inside table
    \begin{tabitemize}
      \item <3-> subitem inside table
    \end{tabitemize}
  \end{tabitemize}
\end{tabular}

Text

\begin{itemize}
  \item<2-> item outside table
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<3-> subitem outside table
  \end{itemize}
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```